# Setup karma to test a node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner

I'm developing a Node.js module, and I want to use Karma to auto-test it while working.

In my config file, I setup this:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  './index.js',
  './test/indexSpecs.js'
],
```

Obviously, since Node.js isn't included in the browser files, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

If i add:

```
files: [
  './node_modules/**/*.js',
  './index.js',
  './test/indexSpecs.js'
],
```

I get a bunch of errors. I think js files get loaded in alphabetical order, which is wrong.

I also think that Node.js cannot be run in a browser, so what I'm trying to do may be totally wrong. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about karma not being a good fit for testing server side code. It is going to run everything in the context of a browser, which is causing the issues you are seeing. If you wanted to develop a module for the server and the client you could use karma in conjunction with browserfiy, but you would still need to run the tests in a node environment.

Instead, I would suggest using [mocha](http://mochajs.org/): a simple and powerful test runner that works great for testing node modules.

Comment: In fact, i'm developping a karma plugin, which is in fact a node.js module. I'm kinda new to javascript, (and node.js), i'll take a look at mocha.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm developing a Node.js module, and I want to use Karma to auto-test
>   it while working.

You should not. Karma is designed for client-side code.

To auto-test your code, the simplest way is to create a npm script similar to this one (with mocha):

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./**",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- -w"
}
```

Then, use `npm test` to run the tests on demand, or `npm run test:watch` to continuously run the tests.

You can also use a grunt or gulp script with a watch task if you prefer.